# how to speed up multiple YT iframes loading time? asynchronous approach with fitvids possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, iframe

setup:

> rails 3.2 - because 4.0 is not here yet ;-)
>
> fitvids (http://fitvidsjs.com) - for responsive iframes
>
> highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com) - for some stats
> ...

and a view with a loop, therefore multiple iframes like:

```
<%= video.each do |video| %>    
    <div class="video-embed">    
      <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= video.host_video_id.strip %>?modestbranding=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;HD=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0?wmode=transparent"  title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
      </iframe>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

fitvids:

```
$(".video-embed").fitVids();
```

when there are more then 10 iframes the page seems to load for 15sec before the highcharts rendering starts. and it looks like hiccups.

I tried the asynchronous approach:

```
(function(d){
  var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

// I tried to include the fitvid code here instead of the following line
  iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:200px;height:100px;left:0px;";
  
  doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
  'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
  'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
  '=\'\/path\/to\/file\'">');
  
  doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

  })(document);
```

it does seem to behave differently, but obviously breaks the fitvid.

is it a) possible to include fitvids into the onload js?
is there b) any other way to make it asynchronously (while using fitvids) load the iframes in order to improve the visual experience? i.e. only render the visible iframes and on a scrolling event render more ... with fitvids?

thank you

j

Comment: Interestingly, http://fitvidsjs.com doesn't work in my Chrome (24.0.1312.57 m)

Comment: thats interesting, because for me it works in chrome 24.0.1312.57 mac

Comment: I was on Win7x64 - however, a different Win7x64 w/ same chrome renders fine - seems like it might've been an issue my end

Comment: It does seem like the question is not precise? or is it just not possible. how can I clarify my question? thank you. j

Comment: I think it's not imprecise but perhaps a little involved - a lot of setup is required to replicate the problem, let alone fix it. If you were to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a minimal test case showing the problem, it might make it easier for others to diagnose